# Iterating through child components

Tags: ember.js

I have **button-group** component which contains a set of **button-element** components. The  template is defined as:

```
{{#each buttons}}
    {{button-element titleBinding="title" action="buttonAction"}}
{{/each}}
```

I'd like the `buttonAction()` method in the `button-group` component to have easy access to the set of `button-element` components and iterate through them. What's the easiest way to do this? I know I could use a jQuery/DOM approach like:

```
this.$('.btn').doSomething();
```

But I'd like to address the component objects not the DOM directly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are iterating over your buttons, in every iteration the `this` variable refers to that button, therefore you could simply define a `button` variable in your component which you set in the iteration:

```
{{#each buttons}}
  {{button-element titleBinding="title" button=this action="buttonAction"}}
{{/each}}
```

so you can then later in the component do something like this:

```
this.get('button').doSomething();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This would give the `button-element`components a pointer back to the `button-group's` buttons[] property but I don't see how this allows the `button-group` to iterate over the various `button-elements`. It's late though, am I being daft?